# Can ARM software exceptions be masked?

Tags: exception, arm, interrupt, interrupt-handling

In ARM CPU architecture, we can mask IRQ, FIQ interrupts by setting the I and F bits of CPSR. But I don’t find any way to mask other exceptions such as reset, undefined instruction, supervisor call, prefetch abort, data abort. Does that mean these exceptions cannot be disabled?

Comment: I believe that is correct.  What do you expect the processor to do when you have a data abort?  Keep going with bad data?  What is it supposed to do with an undefined instruction?

Comment: Haha, @old_timer I just want to confirm that.

Comment: I am not aware of any way to do that on the ARM side, naturally on the chip side the chip vendor could choose to do that and you are welcome to try to read every document of every arm based chip to see if there are exceptions.  Reading the ARM/TRM for each architecture and core is a smaller task.  How many have you read so far (ARM docs)?

Comment: I have read ARM Cortex-A Programmer's Guide for ARMv7 and ARMv8, and ARM Architecture reference manual. What I find is that ARM indeed only mask some exceptions, such as the A, I, F field in CPSR register are used in this purpose. But I don't find any mechanism that can mask software exceptions, so I ask this question to confirm.

Comment: @old_timer I think this question may be an 'obvious' so the ARM technical reference don't mention this. I might be too ‘cautious’.

Comment: if there is a signal or control register bit to mask this that wouldnt be left as obvious, it would be documented.